# Multithreading proplem

Tags: java, multithreading, protocols, network-protocols

I have problem in multitasking. I have explained in below.

- I need to do some process for all users(for instance 200 users) in my
  web app.
- The process is  protocol request call.
- I can able to run up to 1000 users with sleep time between thread creation.
  but I need to run without sleep time and also i need to run up to 1000 users.
- When I try to run for 200 users I am not getting any response. Its stopped for long time. I don't know the reason.

Please let me know If anybody have idea to resolve it
...Thanks...

Comment: Can you post your source code ? It's hard to completely understand the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Agree-- as it stands this *sounds* like some vague description of a homework assignment. *Why* do you need to "run without sleep time"-- you need to explain, with code and more detail, what the Actual Problem is.

Comment: @NeilCoffey My application is going to use by more then 1000 users at a time so with sleep time the users will get time delay to get details from protocol call.

Comment: It's impossible to understand exactly what you're trying to do from the description given, but I suspect that if you think you need to put a sleep in, you're almost certainly doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It sounds to me like it's an issue with creating too many threads too quickly.

Try using some kind of [ThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) to minimize the overhead of thread creation.  Basically you're going to want to have a fixed set of threads that are created, and then re-use those threads for new tasks instead of making a new thread for each task.

If, for example, each task takes 1s to run and you get 2 tasks per second for 100 seconds, the thread-per-task method would create 200 threads to run all tasks.  A pool of 100 threads would be able to execute all 200 tasks using some of those threads more than once and never leaving anything waiting/sleeping.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mr.Brian

Here I have used Thread Pool using following code

Creating Thread pool

private ExecutorService service;
service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

Submitting Thread
Future<some class> future = service.submit(callable object);

Closing Thread

 service.shutdownNow();

Comment: Keep in mind that creating too many threads in your pool may actually decrease performance unless your processing is heavily IO bound